# Keyboard Hook callback Procedure not gets called continously for VC++ X64-bit application on windows X64-bit system

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Keyboard Hook callback Procedure not gets called continously for VC++ X64-bit application on windows X64-bit system.

Mouse & Message Hook set properly using SetWindowsHookEx API in 64-bit application.

Only for keyboard hook its not working , To set keyboard hook below API is used to set it & call the callback procedure i.e.KeyBoardHookProc.

m_hKbHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, &KeyBoardHookProc, AfxGetInstanceHandle(), 0);

For X86 bit application its working on Wndows 7 X86 system successfully.

i have tried below options
1. i have  added message loop  after setting of the keyboard hook .
example: i.e.

```
m_hKbHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, &KeyBoardHookProc, AfxGetInstanceHandle(), 0);

while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
```

2.

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, (HOOKPROC)KeyBoardHookProc, AfxGetInstanceHandle(), 0);
```

both are not working..

Dialog application contains below src to start thread:

```
theApp.m_pthrHookThread = AfxBeginThread(RUNTIME_CLASS(CHookTestThread ), 0, 0, 0);

HHOOK   m_hKbHook;

then load the hook dll at run time for the 

//.h file
class CHookTestThread : public CWinThread
{
}

//.cpp file
BOOL CHookTestThread ::InitInstance()
{
    m_hKbHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, &KeyTestHookProc, AfxGetInstanceHandle(), 0);
    if (!m_hKbHook)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Could not set the lowlevel keyboard hook"));
    }


    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

return (((CHookTestThread *)theApp.m_pthrHookThread )->KeyTestHook(nCode, wParam, lParam));
}

LRESULT CHookTestThread ::KeyTestHook(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

//handle shortcut keys as per virtual key code..

if (nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(m_hKbHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);


return CallNextHookEx(m_hKbHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);

}
```

Expected results:
after setting keyboard hook KeyHookProc must called continously whenever press the key from the keyboard and capture the WM_KEYDOWN or WM_SYKEYDOWN message inside the callback procedure.

Actual Results:
after setting keyboard hook KeyHookProc not called continously whenever we pressed the key from the keyboard. Sometimes it gets called and capture the WM_KEYUP message inside the callback procedure.

Comment: What's the rationale behind the `m_pthrHookThread`, and why is there a `(CHookTestThread *)` in the hook procedure?

Comment: CHookTestThread is the UI Thread which is derived from the CWinThread class & m_pthrHookThread is the handle of the thread

Comment: Calling a member on the `CHookTestThread` class doesn't magically move execution to the thread referenced by its internal handle, which appears to be what you are trying to accomplish.